# IF < TODAY(), >TODAY(), =TODAY(), three different conditions in same cell for different results

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it best to use the IF function if I have three different arguments with their own result, based on the date?

What I want to occur, is if the date in column A is older than today, to return "" or 0 in the labor column in that row.  If TODAY() falls within the week ending date of the date in the A column, then return 230 for Monday, 180 for Tuesday, 135 for Wednesday, 90 for Thursday and 40 for Friday.  And lastly, for all rows that the date in the A column is greater than TODAY()'s date, to return 230.

I've been able to accomplish all this except for returning a value if the date in one cell is greater than today's week ending date.  Excel gives me the error that I have too many nested IF's.  I know that newer versions allow me to use many more nested IF's, but I have to use this version.  Here is a sample of the code

```
{=IF($A32<TODAY(),0, IF(TODAY()=2-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+TODAY(),$T$32,IF(TODAY()=3-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+TODAY(),$U$32,IF(TODAY()=4-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+TODAY(),$V$32,IF(TODAY()=5-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+TODAY(),$W$32,IF(TODAY()=6-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+TODAY(),$X$32))))))}
```

Is there any way to upload a copy of my spreadsheet?  A picture is worth a thousand words

[link to sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ht-VipzjCA3p2lO3F1EEvXfoEWddU0LWxrzLkkqjj78/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1475877/edit) instead of adding information in comments. Clarifying what the desired result is would also be helpful

Comment: `TODAY()=2-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+TODAY()` may as well be written as `WEEKDAY(TODAY())=2`. That said, you may want to try using `INDEX` to choose the right cell in `T32:X32` instead of all those `IF`s. Something like `INDEX(T32:X32,,WEEKDAY(TODAY())-1)`

Comment: You say you want to test 3 conditions, but the code you provided has more conditions, and it does not accomplish what you described. What exactly do you want?

Comment: `=IF($A32<TODAY(),0,INDEX($T$32:$X$32,WEEKDAY(TODAY())-1)`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad, thank you for helping me clean up the formula.  The Weekday(today())=2 worked well.  Your index suggestion didn't work though.  I may be using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I have a formula for you:

```
=IF(TODAY()>This_Week_End, 0, IF(AND(TODAY()>Last_Week_End, TODAY()<=This_Week_End),
    INDEX(Weekday_Amounts, 1, WEEKDAY(TODAY(), 11)), Past_Amount))
```

Where

- `This_Week_End` is the date in the current row
- `Last_Week_End` is the date in the previous row
- `Weekday_Amounts` is the row of amounts, one for each day of the week (including 0 on Saturday and Sunday)
- `Past_Amount` is 230

There are three conditions

1. `TODAY()>This_Week_End` : This row is before `TODAY()`, return `0`
2. `AND(TODAY()>Last_Week_End, TODAY()<=This_Week_End)`: `TODAY()` falls in the week of this row.

   - Use the 2nd argument `11` to `WEEKDAY()` to get it to return 1 on Monday.
   - Use the result of `WEEKDAY` to find which column in the row of weekday amounts to return (as the 3rd argument to the `INDEX()` function)
3. `TODAY() > This_Week_end`: This row is after `TODAY()`, return `230`

I used FormulaChop to generate this example formula. (Full disclosure: I wrote FormulaChop). [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yu0sy.png) is a screenshot of the FormulaChop output. [Here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00560509492785504379) is a link to download the spreadsheet I wrote to prove this. You'll notice it has a "Multi-Step" version of the formula, which spells it out more clearly than the "One-Line" version here.